# Asterisk, Goto+Hungup

Tags: asterisk

There is an extension, for which I need a random sound file to be played, and once it's played the call should be hung up. I have the below dialplan which plays, for example, the 2nd playback and then 3rd one is played etc., but it should hangup after playing back one sound file

```
exten => 123.,7,Goto(${RAND(8,12)}) 
exten => 123.,8,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu1)  
exten => 123.,9,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu2) 
exten => 123.,10,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu3); after playback it supposed rejected.. 
exten => 123.,11,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu4) 
exten => 123.,12,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu5) 
exten => 123.,13,Hangup() 
exten => 123.,14,Hangup(34)
```

How can I make this work; calling, playing only one random menu and hanging up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the hangup command a priority label and add a [`Goto()`](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Goto+Application+and+Priority+Labels) pointing to it after playing each item.

Also:

- if you want to use pattern matching for an extension (I assume that's why you have a dot after 123) you should prefix it with an underscore
- `same` can be used in place of `exten => ...` for the extension when you're repeating the same thing
- `n` can be used for the **n**ext priority so you don't have to worry about keeping all the numbers straight

Now if we get rid of the priority numbers, what do you use in place of `Goto(${RAND(8,12)})`? More labels:

```
[mycontext]
exten => _123.,1,NoOp("start of context")
 ; ...
 same => n,Goto(menu${RAND(1,5)}) 
 same => n(menu1),Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu1)
 same => n,Goto(goodbye)
 same => n(menu2),Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu2) 
 same => n,Goto(goodbye)
 same => n(menu3),Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu3)
 same => n,Goto(goodbye)
 same => n(menu4),Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu4) 
 same => n,Goto(goodbye)
 same => n(menu5),Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu5) 
 same => n(goodbye),Hangup(34)
```

Or, more simply, use the `RAND()` function to choose the name of the file to play:

```
[mycontext]
exten => _123.,1,NoOp("start of context")
 ; ...
 same => n,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customer_Menu${RAND(1,5)})
 same => n,Hangup(34)
```

Comment: I'm agree with the second option, more clean and simple as I can see

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
exten => _123.,7,Set(FILES=customer_Menu1:customer_Menu2:customer_Menu3)
same => n,Playback(${CUT(FILES,:,${RANDOM(1,3)}); CUT will get nth argument delimited by :
same => n,Hangup(34)
```

Or like miken32 show you if your files are always same name.
Also nice idea is move configure variables like FILES in [general] section or special file included in code.

You DO NOT need /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/ before every file. Just check that in your /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf sound path is /var/lib/asterisk/sounds(default).